Flutter iOS Companion App with watchOS target: no such module
I have a Flutter iOS app and recently added a watchOS target, bundling these two apps together. While I can start them from Xcode without any issues, I encounter a problem when trying to start the app via VSCode. The build fails due to a missing dependency, showing the error Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'CryptoSwift'.
CryptoSwift is a pod only used for the watch app. So this issue appears because the iOS app build lacks the necessary dependencies for the watch app. I've also noticed similar occurrences in other logs, where the pods for the watch target appear empty, displaying only the manually added package dependency.
Target 'Watch App' in project 'Runner'
                    ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'SwiftUI Apple Watch Decimal Pad' in project 'SwiftUI Apple Watch Decimal Pad'
                

This error also appears when I try flutter build ipa, which executes the xcodebuild command. I suspect there are some basic configuration issues causing this? Has anyone encountered a similar problem and found a solution? I've been struggling with this for some time now and would appreciate help.
My Podfile looks like this:
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end
  
  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

target 'Runner' do
  platform :ios, '12.0'
  
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

target 'Watch App' do
  platform :watchos, '10.0'
  
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.8.2'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.name == 'Runner'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      elsif target.name == 'Watch App'
        config.build_settings['WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
      else
        # Set the deployment target for all other pods
        if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
        end
        if config.build_settings['WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']
          config.build_settings['WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
        end
      end
    end
end



have you found any solution? I'm facing the same issue

hi, sorry no I have not found a nice way to fix this issue. I reduced the used packages for the watch app to 2 and my workaround was to add the dependencies manually. So I added the code and the files from the dependencies to my project and removed them from the podfile. Not a nice workaround but was the only way how I could make things work. Maybe you will find a better solution
